# Convert varchar in MySql to a given date format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column named 'date' which has type varchar (for reasons) but stores dates in the format- (d-m-Y H:i:s)

Now I have to make a BETWEEN query to find records between two dates. But because the datatype is varchar, I first have to convert the column to date-type and then compare. So I've tried this-

```
    SELECT 
      mobile, 
      STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d') 
   FROM register 
   WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d') 
   BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2017-05-01','%Y-%m-%d') AND
   STR_TO_DATE('2017-05-31','%Y-%m-%d')
```

This query converts the 'date' column to Y-m-d format correctly. But, the two dates given to compare are taken as strings ("2017-05-01" and "2017-05-31") and the result returns records of the date 2017-05-20 only.

What the query should be so that it compares the column and given dates in date-type?

Comment: The str_to_date function call on the date should use a format like how it is stored, not how you want it output.

Comment: You should match your formatting here `STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d')` with the format of the actual content which is `d-m-Y H:i:s`.

Comment: Check out [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: Yes! thanks! converting it to '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s' worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
STR_TO_DATE('DateString', '%e %m %Y %H:%i:%s')
```

**OR**

```
STR_TO_DATE('DateString', '%d %m %Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Comment: converting it to ('%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') worked. Why have you used e instead of d? or is it a typo?

Comment: Yes you can use both, `%e` is a more accurate way of representing the date i.e two digit numbers. PS: You can show your gratitude towards the community by accepting the answer.

Comment: Was just waiting for the clarification of that e! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Match up the format string to how you have it stored:

```
SELECT 
    mobile, 
    STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d') 
FROM register 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y') 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2017-05-01','%Y-%m-%d') AND
STR_TO_DATE('2017-05-31','%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

This query gives what you want

```
SELECT 
   user_id, 
   STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y') 
FROM register 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y') 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('05-01-2015','%d-%m-%Y') AND
STR_TO_DATE('31-05-2017','%d-%m-%Y')
```